# Chromatic number of triangle-free graph $[[n]]^2$ with edges of form $a<b, b<c$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

I am reading (and enjoying!) Bela Bollobas' book "Modern Graph Theory", and one of the exercises shows how to construct triangle-free graphs with large chromatic number:

For any non-negative integer $n$, let $[n]=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, and for any set $X$ let $[X]^2=\big\{\{x,y\}:x\neq y\in X\big\}$. So $[[n]]^2$ is the collection of 2-element sets of $[n]$. Two members $\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}\in [[n]]^2$ form an edge if $\max\{a,b\} = \min\{c,d\}$. Let us call the resulting graph $T_n$. It is easy to see that $T_n$ is triangle-free for all $n\in\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N$. Moreover, $\chi(T_n) \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ as is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/580033).

**Question.** Suppose $n\geq 4$ is an integer and $G$ is a triangle-free graph with $\chi(G) = n$. Is there necessarily $k\in\N$ with $\chi(T_k) \geq n$ and $|V(T_k)| = k(k-1)/2 \leq |V(G)|$?

(Sloppily formulated, are the graphs $T_k$ "most efficient" at being-triangle-free whilst having a large chromatic number?)

Comment: Thanks @bof, yes, I wanted exactly what you made precise in the comment. My question was whether the graphs $[[n]]^2$ were the "most efficient" triangle-free graphs. Have to reformulate

Comment: @bof, I removed the false stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $\chi(T_k)\ge n$ iff $k\gt2^{n-1}$; see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579892). So the smallest $4$-chromatic graph of the form $T_k$ is $T_9$ which has $36$ vertices, or $35$ if we don't count the isolated vertex; but the smallest $4$-chromatic triangle-free graph is the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) with $11$ vertices.

In general, the smallest $n$-chromatic graph of the form $T_k$ is $T_{2^{n-1}+1}$ which has order $\binom{2^{n-1}+1}2=2^{2n-3}+2^{n-2}$, but this is beaten by the [Mycielskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian#Iterated_Mycielskians) $M_n$ which has order $3\cdot2^{n-2}-1$ and is far from being the most efficient.